# Filter out some fields when converting Avro specificrecord to json string

Tags: java, json, deserialization, avro

I have some Avro SpecificRecord that I want to convert to Json string, with several fields to be filtered out. For example, I want to only include the field A and C from the following Event when generating the Json string: is there any existing libraries to do that? Or any suggestions?
`

```
public class Event extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
...
  public String A;
  public String B;
  public long C;
}
```

`

Directly calling toString does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Avro schema with only the subset fields you want. You don't need to  generate a class for that.

Then you can use `JSONDecoder` class to read existing binary Avro data to JSON, and it'll only have those fields in the provided "reader schema".